# Prove by induction that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \frac{1}{(2i-1)}>\frac{n+3}{4}$

Tags: inequality, summation, induction

> Prove **by induction** that
> $$\sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \frac{1}{(2i-1)}>\frac{n+3}{4}$$

I’m having quite some trouble with this one. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: ok, so I've tried rewriting the sum on the lefthand side in a couple of different ways but I didn't get very far. For example,

$\sum_{i=1}^{2^k} \frac{1}{(2i-1)}=\sum_{i=1}^{2^k*2} \frac{1}{(2i-1)} - \sum_{i=2^k}^{2^k*2} \frac{1}{(2i-1)}     $

$\sum_{i=1}^{2^k} \frac{1}{(2i-1)} = \sum_{i=1}^{2^k} (\frac{1}{(2i-1)}-\frac{1}{(2i+1)})+\sum_{i=1}^{2^k}\frac{1}{(2i+1)}   $

Like I said, neither of those ended up being "useful" but I could be overlooking something.

Comment: Welcome. You need a better title. You should also show what your trouble has been

Comment: We have $\sum_{i=1}^{2^{n+1}} \frac{1}{(2i-1)} = \sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \frac{1}{(2i-1)} + \sum_{i=2^{n}+1}^{2^{n+1}} \frac{1}{2i-1} > \frac{n + 3}{4} + 2^n \cdot \frac{1}{2 \cdot 2^{n+1} - 1} > \frac{n+3}{4} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{n + 4}{4}$.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Much appreciated

Comment: @Cono123 You are welcome. You may use @ in your comment, otherwise I can not receive the notification of your reply.